# Не получается из консольного .Net Core сослаться на библиотеку .Net Standard

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, .net-standard

Создал библиотеку `.net-standard`, в ней определил класс `Class1` и константу `MyConst`.

Далее создал консольное приложение `.net-core`, в нём набросал такой код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.MyConst);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

В моем случае .Net Standard имеет версию 1.3, а .Net Core имеет версию 1.0.

UPD: Версия студии:  Microsoft VS Enterprise 2017 v. 15.4.0

**(!)**  Проблема в том, что не получается запустить консольное приложение. Консоль мигает примерно на миллисекунду, но не ведет себя как ожидается, то есть, не выводит константу с содержанием "Hello world" и не останавливается на `Console.ReadLine();`.

В output выводится следующая инфо:

```
Программа "[8376] dotnet.exe" завершилась с кодом -2147450749 (0x80008083).
Программа "[8376] dotnet.exe: Трассировка программы" завершилась с кодом 0 (0x0).
```

Ну да и из картинки видно, что к библиотеке `.net-standard` (в которой класс `Class1`, в котором константа `MyConst`) так же идет обращение из WPF-ного приложения (.Net Framework 4.6). Здесь добавил нугет пакет и ссылка на библиотеку работает нормально, то есть, приложение запускается и константа отображается. Думаю, что этот аспект к теме не относится.

Благодарю!

Comment: Вы версию студии указать забыли

Comment: @PavelMayorov UPD: Версия студии: Microsoft VS Enterprise 2017 v. 15.4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По коду ошибки удалось найти:

- Перечисление `StatusCode`, в котором указано поле с данным значением - [CoreHostLibMissingFailure](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/e53674a25043e5cb1721d639c8026d71d9a08ff7/src/corehost/error_codes.h#L11) ;
- Место где используется поле [CoreHostLibMissingFailure](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/e53674a25043e5cb1721d639c8026d71d9a08ff7/src/corehost/error_codes.h#L11) - [read_config_and_execute](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/e53674a25043e5cb1721d639c8026d71d9a08ff7/src/corehost/cli/fxr/fx_muxer.cpp#L999).

Можно сделать вывод, что отсутствуют требуемые версии библиотек. После установки .NET Core SDK [1.1.10](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-1.1.10-windows-x64-installer) ошибка у меня воспроизводиться перестала.